# Angular - Route Params for child routes

Tags: angular, angular-routing, routeparams

I have the following routing configuration. How would it be possible to access the **:projectId** seen in the parent route from inside the project edit component?

```
 {
        path: 'folders/:folderId/projects/:projectId/s',
        component: ProjectDetailComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
        children: [
            {
                path: 'edit',
                component: ProjectEditComponent,
                canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
            },
            {
                path: 'i',
                component: IssuesListComponent,
                canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
            },
        ],        
    },
```

I previously used this approach when I didn't have children routes:

```
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((urlParameters) => {
  this.project_id = urlParameters['projectId'];
});
```

This no longer works unfortunately.

Comment: Elaborate your question.

Comment: Hey @SunilSingh - I've updated the question. Hopefully that's more precise and better articulated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to access parent route parameters by using [ActivatedRoute parent](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#parent) property:

```
this.activatedRoute.parent.params.subscribe((urlParameters) => {
  this.project_id = urlParameters['projectId'];
});
```

Comment: That's slightly embarrassing...Sorry about that. Thanks haha!

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the projectId in the parent component and pass it to the two child components using @Input